# How can I force a call to onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, onrestoreinstancestate

I've implemented `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` in my android activity.

These seem to work OK, but I'd like to explicitly save the instance state when certain things happen (e.g. when the user presses a button) in case the application crashes, or I terminate it via the debugger

I can call the method obviously, but that doesn't provide the correct Bundle or anything else.

I've looked around, but I can't see any way to do this. Is it possible?

If not, can anyone offer a decent solution for saving activity state at specific points in case of crash/termination?

Thanks

Comment: Saving the bundle in shared preferences?

Comment: Have you tried just keeping a Bundle as a field?

Answer (score 3):

Bundles are only stored in memory, which means even if you manage to put the data into the Bundle it will be gone if your app crashes.

I'd suggest you to use `onSaveInstanceState` for what it's designed for - restoring `Activity` state within an active process. If you want to persist some information so it won't get lost if the app crashes you should use one of the persistent [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Ideally you would have model class for the data that you are displaying. You can persist the model using SQLite and some [DAO library](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO). When you do that you can then restore from the database in onCreate of your `Activity`.

Depending on complexity of the information you can also choose [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). If you have only a few key value pairs this is a good choice and you don't have to use models.